# ansible to create vpc asking for hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, ansible

I'm pretty new to ansible and from reading things what I'm doing should work. I have the following file called `aws.yml`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    aws_region: us-east-1
  tasks:
    - name: Main VPC
      ec2_vpc:
        state: present
        cidr_block: 10.5.0.0/16
        resource_tags: {"environment": "prod"}
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        dns_hostnames: no
        dns_support: yes
        instance_tenancy: default
        internet_gateway: yes
        subnets:
          - cidr: 10.5.151.96/27
            az:  "{{ aws_region }}a"
            resource_tags: {"Name": "private"}
          - cidr: 10.5.151.128/27
            az:  "{{ aws_region }}b"
            resource_tags: {"Name": "private"}
          - cidr: 10.5.151.160/27
            az:  "{{ aws_region }}c"
            resource_tags: {"Name": "private"}
```

When I run ansible-playbook over it I get the following

```
$ ansible-playbook aws.yml
ERROR: Unable to find an inventory file, specify one with -i ?
```

From my understanding is the hosts: localhost is supposed to take the place of using -i and since I'm trying to create a VPC here I don't want to ssh into machines to build it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point to an inventory file (even an empty one), because the playbook only says which hosts the play applies to, but does not provide the means to define such list, the inventory does. Luckily, `localhost` is available by default:

```
$ cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: echo foo

$ ansible-playbook -i /dev/null playbook.yml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK: [shell echo foo] ********************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```